# NGINX Reverse Proxy with Docker Host Mode for Local Development

Tags: docker, nginx, localhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

Most of the things I'm finding online are all about using docker-compose and more to create a reverse proxy for local development of dockerized applications. This is for my local development environment.

I have a need to create an nginx reverse proxy that can route requests to applications on my local computer that are not running in docker containers (non-dockerized).

Example:

- I start up a web app A (not in docker) running on http://localhost:8822
- I start up another web app B (not in docker) running on https://localhost:44320
- I have an already running publicly available api on https://public-url-for-api-app-a.net

I also have a public A Record setup in my DNS for *.mydomain.local.com -> 127.0.0.1

I am trying to figure out how to use a `nginx:mainline-alpine` container in host mode to allow me to do the following:

- I type http://web-app-a.mydomain.local.com -> reverse proxy to http://localhost:8822
- I type http://web-app-b.mydomain.local.com -> reverse proxy to https://localhost:44320
- I type http://api-app-a.mydomain.local.com -> reverse proxy to https://public-url-for-api-app-a.net

Ideally, this "solution" would run on both Windows and Mac but I am currently falling short in my attempts at this on my Windows machine.

Some stuff I've tried:

- Following [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/), Start up my nginx docker container in "host" mode via:

  - `docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx:mainline-alpine`
  - I'm unable to get it to load on http://localhost:80. I'm wondering if I'm hitting some limitation of docker and windows? -- I receive a "The site can't be reached" here.
- Custom building my own docker image with nginx configs and exposed ports (before trying host network mode)

Other relevant information:

- Docker-Desktop on Windows version: 4.4.4 (73704)
- Nginx Container via `nginx:mainline-alpine` tag.
- Web App A = Front End Vue App
- Web App B = Front End .NET Framework App
- Web App C = Backend .NET Framework App

At this point, I've read too many posts that my brain is mush -- so it could very well be something obvious I'm missing. I'm beginning to think it may be better to simply run `nginx.exe` locally but that's not ideal because I don't want to have to check in binaries to my source in order for this setup to work.

Comment: The tutorial you are referring to says the following: _The `host` networking driver only works on Linux hosts, and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server._

Comment: At least on MacOS, you can just `brew install nginx`.  If nothing else in this setup is running in Docker, it might be easier to run the reverse proxy outside a container as well.

Comment: @IvanShatsky - that is true. I was hoping the documentation was outdated or something since there's been many updates to Docker in the last 6mo (wishful thinking I know) -- Assuming it is NOT outdated, is there any way to do this?

Comment: @alexinslc I don't know. I don't understand what you are meaning saying _I don't want to have to check in binaries to my source in order for this setup to work_, maybe my English is not good enough, but I'd rather use the local nginx install and don't bother with the Docker at all.

Comment: Yeah, @IvanShatsky - that's what David Maze also said. In a perfect world, I wanted to have a custom docker image with my nginx configs I could share with people working on my project. It's looking like running local nginx may be the easier route?

Comment: @alexinslc I think it is, and you can share your nginx config files as well.